# What am I? I can be green but then I can hardly be seen

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I can be green
but then I can hardly be seen

I can be yellow
and people will let me mellow

I make people dance
but they won't like the chance

I like to be this way around but when you think not
I might as well fly or hover around a pot

what am I?

Hint #1

> I might be hiding in front of you right now! (not in all Cases)

Hint #2

> If you need to answer just hit me already.

Hint #3

> I can be seen 5 times in the riddle, but not in the hints

---

This is my first puzzle/riddle attempt, so go easy on me. (Other great puzzles on this site inspired me to try rhyming.) Don't think too literally: all the clues don't have to belong together.

Comment: pixels............

Comment: hmmm...I am not seeing it, so may be its green this time. is it by chance some insect?

Comment: Maybe a bee or a fly?

Comment: No it's not an insect but Gandalf here is on the right track

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What am I?

> The letter 'P'

I can be green but then I can hardly be seen

> A pea is relatively small and thus is harder to see. Thanks to @SlashmanX

I can be yellow and people will let me mellow

> Referencing pee in the phrase: "If it's yellow, let it mellow; if it's brown, flush it down" Thanks to @David Starkey

I make people dance but they won't like the chance

> If someone peed on you, chances are high you will do a little dance to try to avoid getting hit with much of it. Also you most likely don't like it.

or

> If you have to pee you will make a funny dance but you rather go before it comes that far since it is quite unpleasant. Thanks to @SlashmanX

I like to be this way around but when you think not I might as well fly or hover around a pot

> If you turn 'P' around you get 'b' as in a bee flying/hovering around a honeypot. Thanks to @Tom

Hint #2

> If you need to answer just hit me already.

V

> I obviously had to hit the letter 'P' on my keyboard ;)

Hint #3

> I can be seen 5 times in the riddle, but not in the hints.

V

> The letter 'P' is found five times in the riddle but not one time in the hints.

Comment: "green" could be the vegetable (which is small), the "dance" hint could be referring to when people really need to go ?

Comment: For 'I like to be this way around ...' you could turn your answer upside down.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. It's all about phonetics. Some of your reasonings are a bit odd (namely the first one) so you might want to work on those :)

Comment: I was too determined to make a funny wrong answer and didn't see the big picture. I will improve the reasoning based on previous comments.

Comment: I think the yellow is reference to the the phrase "If it's yellow, let it mellow; if it's brown, flush it down" (i.e. urine)

Comment: @DavidStarkey I did not know the phrase so it didn't come to mind but it fits perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I believe this is:

> Fire

I can be green...

> Green flame is nearly invisible

I can be yellow...

> People use candles which have yellow flames

I make people dance...

> If you're on fire, you're supposed to stop, drop, and roll, which could be seen as a dance which people wouldn't like to do

I like to be this way around...

> When you have a pot on a gas stove, the flame surrounds the bottom of the pot

Comment: Very creative, but not the answer that I was looking for. :)

Comment: @Toteemi oh alright, a hint by any chance?

Answer (score 9):

It's

> pee.

Reasoning:
I can be green but then I can hardly be seen

> Concentrated urine is green, which you hopefully don't see all too often.

I can be yellow and people will let me mellow

> As the saying goes, "If it's yellow, let it mellow. If it's brown, flush it down".

I make people dance but they won't like the chance.

> People 'dance' when desperate to urinate.

I don't have a reason for the fourth part, but from hint #3:

> The letter 'P' appears five times in the riddle but isn't in any of the hints.

Comment: Partially correct! You're right and your reasoning is good for the most parts. Good job

Comment: for the green one, think of a homonym and where you might have trouble seeing that

Comment: From my comment on another answer to help your reasoning - When you turn the letter "P" upside down, it becomes a "b", as in a bee, which likes to fly and hover around a pot.

Comment: and for the "other way around" think of a letter with a similar shape, then your first answer word with that letter swapped in

Answer (score 5):

it can be

> wasp or bee

I can be green I can be yellow

> it can be yellow or green

I make people dance but they won't like the chance

> well in this case its a dance to get away from it

I like to be this way around but when you think not I might as well fly or hover around a pot

> check out the flower pot in the corner

Comment: Not an insect. For good effort I added some more hints!

Comment: @Toteemi is it close or far from close....btw following your recent hint, I am seeing 5 Is in the riddle.....so is the answer I i.e. toteemi?

Comment: There are I's in the hints also, so no dice. I liked the "bee" part but  there's still few logical leaps to make.

Answer (score 3):

It could be:

> an integrated circuit chip.

I can be green

> ICs are usually green, but people rarely see them.

I can be yellow

> Some chips are yellow, like phone SIM cards.

Make people dance

> Sounds for dancing are provided by the help of integrated chips.

I like to be this way around

> The internet is all over the world.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's

> a leaf.

Reasoning:

I can be green but then I can hardly be seen

> leaves are green, and sometimes they can be nearly invisible.

I can be yellow and people will let me mellow

> leaves turn yellow in the fall

I make people dance but they won't like the chance

> this I'm not sure about. Maybe trying to catch a falling leaf?

I like to be this way around but when you think not I might as well fly or hover around a pot

> If you have a potted plant, leaves might fall off.

Comment: Not a leaf. Good reasoning though. You were closer with the "bee or fly" -guess (still not an insect of any sort).

Answer (score 1):

Probably false, but it could be

> 'key'

I can be green but then I can hardly be seen

> Green screens are often used for chroma keying, a video-editing technique that makes green objects transparent (hard to be seen).

I make people dance but they won't like the chance

> A music key!

I might be hiding in front of you right now! (not in all Cases)

> Assuming we're not on mobile, there's a good chance there's a keyboard in front of us. Also 'Cases' could allude to the 'Caps Lock' or 'Shift' key.

If you need to answer just hit me already.

> Press the 'enter' key to submit.

No idea for these ones yet:

I can be seen 5 times in the riddle, but not in the hints

I can be yellow and people will let me mellow

I like to be this way around but when you think not I might as well fly or hover around a pot

Comment: apologies, I've just checked my inbox and shows I dvoted this answer yesterday - it must have been a mistake on my mobile. I can't correct this now (unless it was edited). I owe you rep!!!